# How can I find a button's size and location in another application?

Tags: c#

I want to find the size and location of the button highlighted in the picture below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jFCD.jpg

I've tried using Microsoft's Spy++ to do this, but it doesn't highlight any controls as shown in the picture below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zovxs.jpg

Any ideas on what I can do to find the LAUNCH button's size and location in the application?

I'll be using C# to automatically click the button once I learn the answer to my question. I'm not sure what tags I should use besides c#.

Comment: It must not be a native button.  Have you checked to see if this application makes any HTTP requests?  It could be an embedded webpage.

Comment: @Amy It makes a lot of HTTP requests when the application loads. I checked using Wireshark.

Comment: Okay.  Spy++ only works with native controls.  It may be possible to intercept the HTML and inject your own JavaScript that will invoke the button.

Comment: @Amy That's a little out of my knowledge base. Are there any other options? I would just like to know the exact size and location of the button inside of the application so I can use that information to send a click to a random x y coordinate inside of the button's range.